# Set CSS styling property based on property value in CSS Class

Tags: css, sass

Consider an element that has a class such as 'my-css-class'. This class is defined as:

```
my-css-class {
  font-family: 'RobotoBold';
  text-transform: lowercase;
  ... (some other properties)
}
```

Is there a way in SCSS to set a particular property (say font-weight or font-style or background-color) to a value based on font-family being a certain value?

For instance, if font-family is set to 'RobotoBold', set the font-weight to bold. Similarly, if font-family is set to 'RobotoItalic', set the font-style to italic. The set of font-families is small can I can enumerate over those, if needed.

Constraints: There are numerous classes and it is not practical to change the name of each class so that I can pattern match on CSS class names. It is also not practical to change the HTML since there are many elements.

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? That you define a `Roboto` font-family in your app via `@font-face` where you specify `RobotoBold.otf` for `font-weight: bold` and `RobotoItalic.otf` for `font-style: italic` etc. and then only need to apply `bold` or `italic` to your elements and the correct font is used automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This simple jQuery codes would do the job

```
if( $(".my-css-class").css('font-family').toLowerCase() == 'robotobold') {
    $(".my-css-class").css('font-weight', 'bold');
}
```

If you can assign your font name to a variable then it is possible in SCSS too:

```
$myfont: 'robotobold';

.my-css-class{
    font-family: $myfont;
    
    @if ($myfont == robotobold){
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the question: "*Is there a way in SCSS to set a particular property..?*" jQuery isn't mentioned as available, nor is it tagged in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. I think your solution will work in general, but due to various complicated reasons, I cannot use jQuery in this fix.